# How are files/dirs hidden from ls -a while still being accessible otherwise in a POSIX compliant system?

Tags: filesystems, posix, zfs, dot-files

For example, in ZFS under FreeBSD and ZoL, there is a magic `.zfs` dir inside of each zpool mountpoint and you can use `zfs set snapdir=visible` to make that `.zfs` dir visible.

What makes me curious is: if that setting is set to "hidden", **how is the `.zfs` dir actually hidden from the output of an `ls -a`** or shell path-auto-completion, while still being accessible otherwise (you can still `cd` to it or call `stat` on it)?

I can't really wrap my mind around this fact, because I somehow think if something is there and accessible it's supposed to be listed in `ls -a` -- even if it's just magic/virtual in nature.

Can anybody explain how this works? Is there a POSIX conforming way to have a directory that is hidden from `ls -a` while still being accessible? How do you do it?

Comment: One good reason to "hide" the `.zfs` directory from `ls` (and other user-space utilities that use `readdir()`) is to see what happens with the `.zfs` directory *visible*.  Run something like `find . -name somefilename` with a visible `.zfs` directory, the `find` utility will descend into the `.zfs` directory and search through every single snapshot for that file name, as well as the actual "active" filesystem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, how to do it is easy enough: `ls` gets its list from a syscall (or, on Linux, libc function) called `readdir`. Changing into a directory is done with a separate syscall, `chdir`. `stat` is also a different syscall, as are most of the other file operations.

In short, "what's in this directory?" and "access this directory" are completely separate requests of the kernel—so they can be programmed to work differently.

So, to make a directory that doesn't appear in `ls -a`, you just have the kernel omit it from the results of `readdir`. But it still works with `chdir` (etc.), because that's a different syscall.

This isn't so different from having a directory where you have `+x` permission, but *not* `-r`: you can access files and directories inside it, `cd` into it, etc., but `ls` will fail. I believe other things have used this arrangement too—for example (and this is from fuzzy memory without looking it up) AFS had a sort-of global `/afs` namespace where you could connect to any AFS server essentially by `cd`'ing into its name; an `ls` on `/afs` wouldn't show all the world's servers, though. I've seen FUSE filesystems do similar (e.g., `cd` to connect to an anonymous FTP server).

(I'm not sure whether the zfs arrangement strictly complies with POSIX).

Comment: On Linux, there's a `getdents()` system call that winds up calling the VFS's `readdir()` implementation, so it's trivial for the ZFS implementation to omit the `.zfs` entry if the `snapdir` property is set to `hidden`. See http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/readdir.c?v=2.6.35 for source.  The [POSIX ls specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ls.html) seems worded such that leaving the directory out isn't in strict compliance with the standard but I suppose one could argue the "directory" is an implementation detail that's optionally exposed as a directory.

Comment: This complies with POSIX because the behavior is indistinguishable from having a concurrent process that always deletes the hidden file just before anyone tries to list it (e.g. by calling `readdir`) and creates it just before anyone tries to access it (e.g. by calling `chdir`).